# Settings Trouble in C#?

Tags: c#, winforms, settings, visual-c#-express-2010

I am having some trouble with my code that is supposed to redo the changes made by the user in the settings. When I click no after closing the form, the `ribbonBar2` goes away, but when I open the settings up, the checkbox is still checked, although it isn't supposed to be. Why?

```
Form1 frm1;
public Form8(Form1 frm1): this()
{
    this.frm1 = frm1;
}

private void checkBox1_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{             
    frm1.ribbonBar2.Visible = checkBox1.Checked;            
}

private void form8_closing(object sender, FormClosingEventArgs e)
{
    Properties.Settings.Default.checkBox1 = checkBox1.Checked;

    DialogResult result1 = MessageBox.Show("Do you want to Save your Settings?", "Warning!", MessageBoxButtons.YesNo, MessageBoxIcon.Warning);
    if (result1 == DialogResult.Yes)
    {
        Properties.Settings.Default.Save();
    }

    if (result1 == DialogResult.No)
    {
        checkBox1.Checked = !Properties.Settings.Default.checkBox1;
    }

    e.Cancel = false;  
}
```

Comment: Please, never write `== true`. Besides that... `checkBox1.Checked = !Properties.Settings.Default.checkBox1`

Comment: It's not clear what you're trying to achieve, or what *exactly* you mean by "when I open the settings up". Bear in mind you're not saving the settings if the user clicks no, so you shouldn't be surprised that the change doesn't make it into the settings file.

Comment: ok, when i click no, i want the checkbok1.checked = false; and i want the ribbon form to visible = false;

Comment: for some reason the Checkbox is not being unchecked, but the ribbon bar is being invisible like it is suposed to

Comment: You did your best saving the setting, possibly over-done.  Well over-done.  But forgot about restoring it, naming the property "checkbox1" won't help.  Add a line to the constructor.

Comment: @HansPassant can you help me with this question...Everyone has nothing but bad comments and such..i am just 16, and am learning C#

Comment: @EliteGamer: First up, read my guide to asking a good question: http://tinyurl.com/so-hints

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As it looks like no one is willing to help you with this...

You don't restore any setting that you saved. If I understand you right, you want to do something like this:

```
public Form8(Form1 frm1): this()
{
    // Restore the settings when loading the form
    checkBox1.Checked = Properties.Settings.Default.checkBox1;
}

private void form8_closing(object sender, FormClosingEventArgs e)
{
    if (DialogResult.Yes == MessageBox.Show("Do you want to Save your Settings?",
                    "Warning!", MessageBoxButtons.YesNo, MessageBoxIcon.Warning))
    {
        // Set the setting and save it
        Properties.Settings.Default.checkBox1 = checkBox1.Checked;
        Properties.Settings.Default.Save();
    }
}
```